# Which package did kernel modules move to between 12.04 to 14.04?

Tags: drivers, kernel

The kernel modules (`/lib/modules/<kernel-version>/*/*.ko`) files that used to be in `linux-image-<version>` packages in 12.04 are no longer there. This includes GPU DRM kernel drivers for video cards (e.g. `radeon.ko`).

**Sidenote**:
This was the reason for no graphics after upgrade, in my case (I use the open-source radeon driver for Radeon X1400). Upgrade (using cmd line client) did not go smoothly due to unrelated local issues, but upon failing it threw me into a shell and after fixing the problem and closing that shell, the upgrade manager retried, and the upgrade seemed to have succeeded. But, it did not update the kernel nor did it install `linux-image-extra-<version>`. It took a while to figure out that this new package was born and that its absence was the reason for the broken graphics.

Answer (score 1):

Between LTS 12.04 and LST 14.04, some of the kernel modules moved from `linux-image-<version>` package to `linux-image-extra-<version>` package. Install it manually if it has not been installed:

```
sudo apt-get install linux-image-extra-$(uname -r)
```